# How to view print_r values

Tags: php, printing, screen-scraping

I have been given this php code

```
echo "<pre>";
    print_r(htmlentities($data));
echo "</pre>";
```

I am really not into php programming and I really don't know where am I gonna see the output of the print_r function. Such a petty question but I hope I could get a decent answer. Thanks!

Comment: What does this have to do with either printing or screen-scraping?

Comment: screen-scraping @BenM

Comment: But how? What's it got to do with it?

Comment: I have some curl commands (which I also do not understand much). The output is displayed through the print_r function. I do not see the content on the page that's why I asked where can I find the output. I guess there's something wrong with the curl commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes to PHP's output buffer.  If you are running the script from a command line client the output will display on the terminal but typically PHP is run on a web server upon the request of a user.  In the latter case, if your script was named 'example.php' and accessible at http://example.com/example.php visiting that URL would show the output in the web browser.

Answer (score 2):

As per the PHP manual: `print_r`: 'Prints human-readable information about a variable'. Assuming that `$data` is an array, you will have an output of that data as plain text - it is basically `var_dump` (the main difference is that `var_dump` will also output types).

```
$data = array('item', 'name', 'form');
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => item
    [1] => name
    [2] => form
)
```

However, keep in mind `htmlentities` is looking for a string; and if you input an array you will get an error. So if you do have a string it would be okay to use `htmlentities`

```
<?php
$data = 'Hello World!';
echo "<pre>";
    print_r(htmlentities($data));
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Output:

```
Hello World!
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was actually starting to learn web scraping. It was a good help!

Comment: Cheers mate! My pleasure @adrianquevada

Answer (score 1):

Should display right at the top of your page you're running.  print_r displays an arrays contents. You're better off doing this:

```
$array = ("cat","dog");

echo "<xmp>";
   print_r($data);
echo "</xmp>";
```

So in the browser navigate to page.php, it'll display your array. Now if you're in command line doing this it'll come to the output buffer but that depends on your setup.